Suggestions on dynamodb table design
I am looking for help on design the dynamodb table. Here is my usecase,
Currently, i have a set of actions that user can complete at any point of time. These actions keep on changes based on the user actions on account level by group. And these actions are grouped. meaning, user can belong to multiple groups. i wanted to track these actions in dynamo table.
i did came up with two designs in dynamo. i am not sure, which has better approach according to dynamo standards.
Design-1
accountid (PK) -- groupName (SK) -- json
1234567891023    -- groupName1234  -- { clicked: true, opened: true }

Note: Here JSON won't be reaching more than 20kb.

Design-2
accountid (PK) -- groupName (SK) -- action -- status
1234567891023   -- groupName1234 -- clicked  -- true
1234567891023   -- groupName1234 -- opened  -- true
And we are expecting to have more than 2 million records to start with. Based on the data, which design would be the good option here?
operations we are planning to do on this table

Retrieving all the actions that the account did
Retrieving all the actions that the account did by group

I am not sure, whether to go with a JSON-based data model or a top-level attribute-based model.

Your basically asking if you should store your data as nested JSON or as top level attributes? As your keys don't change, both models are equal for your access.
However, storing as top level attributes can provide better flexibility, you can create an index on an attribute of needed for example.

Thanks, Lerroy. yeah, I am not sure whether to go with nested JSON or top-level attribute. As you mentioned, from an access point of view both models are suitable. Looks like the top-level attribute model is more flexible than JSON-based.

if I go with the top-level attribute, is it still performant while scanning or querying based on the PK and SK vs json based model?

Yes, nothing changes.

With top-level attributes you will be able to perform query operations over the table by other attributes expect the primary key & sort key, by adding secondary indexes for the table.
If the combination of accountid & groupName (a record) may contain some complex data such as aggregations and multi level hierarchy objects, it can be more convenient to use JSON.
So if the tables attributes will stays as now - "primitive" types it would be better for flexibility to declare it at top level.
